# Get String from Spring FTP streaming Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: spring, ftp, stream, spring-integration

I have the following code which works OK retrieving files from FTP server into a stream, but I need to get String of each file, seems I need to use the Transformer passing a charset but what I'm missing? How exactly to get the content String of each file transferred?

Thanks a lot in advance

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class FtpinboundApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FtpinboundApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FtpinboundApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("X.X.X.X");
        sf.setPort(21);
        sf.setUsername("xxx");
        sf.setPassword("XXX");
        return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "stream")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println("trasnferred file:" + message.getPayload());

            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "stream", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1000"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {

        FtpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpStreamingMessageSource(template(), null);
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("/X/X/X");
        messageSource.setFilter(new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "streaming"));
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
       @Transformer(inputChannel = "stream", outputChannel = "data")
       public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer() {
           return new StreamTransformer("UTF-8");
       }

       @Bean
       public FtpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
           return new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(ftpSessionFactory());
       }


    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5000));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StreamTransformer` to get the whole file as a single string, or a `FileSplitter` to get a message for each line.

**EDIT (filter config)**

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "stream")
public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {
    FtpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpStreamingMessageSource(template(), null);
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("ftpSource/");
    messageSource.setFilter(filter());
    return messageSource;
}

public FileListFilter<FTPFile> filter() {
    CompositeFileListFilter<FTPFile> filter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    filter.addFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
    filter.addFilter(acceptOnceFilter());
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter acceptOnceFilter() {
    FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter filter = new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(meta(),
            "streaming"); // keys will be, e.g. "streamingfoo.txt"
    filter.setFlushOnUpdate(true);
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore meta() {
    PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore meta = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
    meta.setBaseDirectory("/tmp/foo");
    meta.setFileName("ftpStream.properties");
    return meta;
}
```

**EDIT2 - remove remote file with an advice**

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "data", adviceChain = "after")
@Bean
public MessageHandler handle() {
    return System.out::println;
}

@Bean
public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice after() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setOnSuccessExpression(
            "@template.remove(headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile'])");
    advice.setPropagateEvaluationFailures(true);
    return advice;
}
```

Comment: Gary, thanks yes actually I have:   @Bean
        @Transformer(inputChannel = "stream", outputChannel = "data")
        public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer() {
            return new StreamTransformer("UTF-8");
        } but I'm not really sure where to use it in the code.

Comment: You currently have your service activator and transformer both subscribed to `stream` - this means messages will be sent alternately to each - you need to subscribe your service activator to the transformer's output channel.

Comment: Oh! I see. I get it now! thanks Gary, seizing your generosity could you let me know how to set the streaming message source filter to only get certain files from the server? I can't find something clear (for me) in the documentation and it seems different than the standard FTP inbound channel.

Comment: See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-streaming) - the `filter` can be anything you like, such as the provided `SimplePatternFileListFilter` or a `RegexPatternFileListFilter`. If you don't remove the remote files after processing (e.g. with an outbound gateway with `rm` command) you will also need a persistent accept once file list filter.

Comment: Hi Gary, since I want to prevent duplicates and use a Filter, I try to implement  CompositeFileListFilter but I'm not totally sure how, could you give me some light here?   Also not sure what the MetadataStore.remove key refers to.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. If you remove a key (`prefix+filename`)  from the store, or the remote file timestamp changes, the file will be re-fetched.

Comment: This has worked beautifully, I would appreciate your comments in more thing; Is there a way to delete the remote files transferred with the FTP Streaming Adapter or I must use a Gateway or something else?

Comment: You should really be asking new questions instead of keep adding new questions to this one. See my second edit.